# Discord.py react with emoji to a message

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def react(ctx):
    emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
    await ctx.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Doesnt work if I type ".react"

I want the bot to react with a specific emoji on the message if a user types ".react"

Comment: Try `ctx.message.add_reaction` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any extra context, I can't really tell what is causing your issue. However, one thing does stand out is that the `add_reaction` method is a member of the `message` attribute of `ctx`, not `ctx directly. This means you need to access it first, e.g:

```py
await ctx.message.add_reaction()
```

Changing that might not solve your issue though, especially if you are not getting an error. Do you have `@commands.command()` or `@client.command()` before your `async def react`?

Your overall code should look something like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@bot.command()
async def react(ctx):
    emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji)

bot.run('token')
```